# Create view from select with parameters

Tags: mysql, view, parameters

I want to create view from this 'select'

```
CREATE VIEW `ste_15` AS
set @n:=0;
select 
       instr_name,
       min(instr_bid) as minBid,
       max(instr_bid) as maxBid,
       avg(instr_bid) as avgBid,
       STR_TO_DATE(instr_modifie,'%c/%d/%Y %T') + interval @n*15 minute as timescale,@n:=@n+1
from dfhistory
where
instr_modifie is not null
group by instr_modifie;
```

But mysql give me an syntax error near 'set @n:=0 ....'. How can I create view with parameter?

Comment: You can't use variables in a view definition.

Comment: So, if I can't use variables, how I can create view with max,min,avg and select data only with 15 minutes interval?

Comment: Please add example data and expected output. It is not clear what you try to achieve.